# How to maintain the values of a variable when refreshing the page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have a canActivate method. When I sing in on my website I set a variable of type boolean true. And my canActivate work with this variable. But if I refresh the page the value return to false. I need mantain the value if the page refresh

Codes

```
export class AuthService{
   loggedin = false;

   isAuthenticated(){
     return this.loggedin;
   }

   login(){
     this.loggedin = true;
   }

   logout(){
     this.loggedin = false;
   }
}
```

and canActivate

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{

   constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{
     if(this.authService.isAuthenticated()){
       return true;
     }else{
       this.router.navigate(['/']);
     }
   }
}
```

when I make the login I call the function login and set the value to true. But If I reload the page the value reset to false. I need to make the true in the value. The value one way to change the value is call the method logout. Why I can do this?

Comment: Use localStorage to persist data on page referesh

Comment: https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage

Comment: localstorage will be used to retrieve parameter at every tab of the browser, however sessionstorage does not keep values for different browser tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `localStorage`, here are your refactored methods, should work as is:

```
   isAuthenticated(){
     return localStorage.getItem('loggedin', true);
   }

   login(){
     localStorage.setItem('loggedin', true);
   }

   logout(){
     localStorage.removeItem('loggedin'); // here you can either remove the item or use setItem and simply assign a false value localStorage.setItem('loggedin', false);
   }
```

Now when you refresh, your app will check isAuthenticated() which will in turn check the storage for the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you use localStorage.setItem(), there will be a bug that even you restart the browser the variable is still there, maybe a user login info, and this is unacceptable.
Using **window.sessionStorage["xxx"]** is a better way, this makes the variable only valid in one session, if the browser is restarted, the variable becomes invalid, this is more likely the common scenario.